# Is there any JNI-like mechanism allowing C code to paint a Java control directly?

Tags: java, c++, graphics, java-native-interface

I'm happy to rewrite a given C++ app in Java, but the main rendering task would be 1) a LOT of work to port and 2) probably suffer in performance.

Comment: I know that there are Java programs that use OpenGL for rendering. Additionally there are related question here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793593

Comment: Have you looked into the [AWT native interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/awt/AWT_Native_Interface.html)?

Comment: You might also look into how SWT does its AWT bridge. This puts a native control into an AWT frame, that you can paint on.